# NodeJs Script that compiles scss files fails because of postcss rule for undefined variables

Tags: node.js, sass, postcss

I am using [scss-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-bundle) to import an `scss` file and resolve all his `@import` statements to later save it again as `scss` file.

This works fine and below is an example to see how it works:

**scss-bundle.ts**

```
import { Bundler } from 'scss-bundle';
import { relative } from 'path';
import { writeFile } from 'fs-extra';

/** Bundles all SCSS files into a single file */
async function bundleScss(input, output) {
  const {found, bundledContent, imports} = await new Bundler()
    .Bundle(input, ['./src/styles/**/*.scss']);
  if (imports) {
    const cwd = process.cwd();

    const filesNotFound = imports
      .filter((x) => !x.found)
      .map((x) => relative(cwd, x.filePath));

    if (filesNotFound.length) {
      console.error(`SCSS imports failed \n\n${filesNotFound.join('\n - ')}\n`);
      throw new Error('One or more SCSS imports failed');
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    await writeFile(output, bundledContent);
  }
}

bundleScss('./src/styles/file-to-import.scss', './src/styles/imported-file.scss');
```

Where `file-to-import.scss` is the following file:

```
@import './file-to-import-1';
@import './file-to-import-2';
```

And `file-to-import-1.scss` and `file-to-import-2.scss` are the following files:

**file-to-import-1.scss**

```
.price-range {
  background-color: $range-header-background-1;
}
```

**file-to-import-2.scss**

```
.qr-code {
  background-color: $range-header-background-2;
}
```

The result of executing the script is:

**imported-file.scss**:

```
.price-range {
  background-color: $range-header-background-1;
}

.qr-code {
  background-color: $range-header-background-2;
}
```

Until this everything is working well.

**Now ...** I want to use [postcss-css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) in order to hash the names of the classes, the result should be something like this:

**imported-file.scss** after being hashed

```
._3BQkZ {
  background-color: $range-header-background-1;
}

.Xb2EV {
  background-color: $range-header-background-2;
}
```

I have already achieved that but only if I define the variables `$range-header-background-1` and `$range-header-background-2`.

**However, I can not define the variables yet because I need to defined them on run time as query params of an Http request.**

If I run the script without defining the variables the following error is display:

```
(node:1972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): CssSyntaxError: <css input>:372:14: Unknown word
(node:1972) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is the `scss-budle.ts` with `postcss-css-modules` call:

```
import { Bundler } from 'scss-bundle';
import { relative } from 'path';
import * as path from 'path';
import { writeFile } from 'fs-extra';
import * as postcssModules from 'postcss-modules';
import * as postcss from 'postcss';
import * as fs from 'fs';

/** Bundles all SCSS files into a single file */
async function bundleScss(input, output) {
  const {found, bundledContent, imports} = await new Bundler()
    .Bundle(input, ['./src/styles/**/*.scss']);
  if (imports) {
    const cwd = process.cwd();

    const filesNotFound = imports
      .filter((x) => !x.found)
      .map((x) => relative(cwd, x.filePath));

    if (filesNotFound.length) {
      console.error(`SCSS imports failed \n\n${filesNotFound.join('\n - ')}\n`);
      throw new Error('One or more SCSS imports failed');
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    await writeFile(output, bundledContent);

    const hashedResult = await postcss().use(postcssModules({
      generateScopedName: '[hash:base64:5]',
      getJSON(cssFileName: any, json: any, outputFileName: any) {
        let jsonFileName = path.resolve('./src/styles/imported-file.json');
        fs.writeFileSync(jsonFileName, JSON.stringify(json));
      }
    })).process(bundledContent);
    await writeFile(output.replace('.scss', '-hashed.scss'), hashedResult.css, 'utf8');
    return;
  }

}

bundleScss('./src/styles/file-to-import.scss', './src/styles/imported-file.scss');
```

Does anybody know how to continue executing `postcss-css-modules` without stopping because the scss variables are not defined?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run the script successfully using [postcss-scss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss) as parser of [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss):

```
import * as postcssScss from 'postcss-scss';

...

const hashedResult = await postcss([
  postcssModules({
    generateScopedName: '[hash:base64:8]',
    getJSON(cssFileName: any, json: any, outputFileName: any) {
        let jsonFileName = path.resolve('./src/styles/imported-file.json');
        fs.writeFileSync(jsonFileName, JSON.stringify(json));
    }
  })
]).process(bundledContent, { parser: postcssScss});
```

Below, I leave the script complete:

**scss-bundle.ts**

```
import { Bundler } from 'scss-bundle';
import { relative } from 'path';
import * as path from 'path';
import { writeFile } from 'fs-extra';
import * as postcssModules from 'postcss-modules';
import * as postcss from 'postcss';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as postcssScss from 'postcss-scss';

/** Bundles all SCSS files into a single file */
async function bundleScss(input, output) {
  const {found, bundledContent, imports} = await new Bundler()
    .Bundle(input, ['./src/styles/**/*.scss']);
  if (imports) {
    const cwd = process.cwd();

    const filesNotFound = imports
      .filter((x) => !x.found)
      .map((x) => relative(cwd, x.filePath));

    if (filesNotFound.length) {
      console.error(`SCSS imports failed \n\n${filesNotFound.join('\n - ')}\n`);
      throw new Error('One or more SCSS imports failed');
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    await writeFile(output, bundledContent);

    const hashedResult = await postcss([
      postcssModules({
        generateScopedName: '[hash:base64:8]',
        getJSON(cssFileName: any, json: any, outputFileName: any) {
            let jsonFileName = path.resolve('./src/styles/imported-file.json');
            fs.writeFileSync(jsonFileName, JSON.stringify(json));
        }
      })
    ]).process(bundledContent, { parser: postcssScss});
    await writeFile(output.replace('.scss', '-hashed.scss'), hashedResult.css, 'utf8');
    return;
  }
}

bundleScss('./src/styles/file-to-import.scss', './src/styles/imported-file.scss');
```